# Fabric git push asking for passphrase, though command line version doesn't

Tags: git, fabric

If I run the `git push` command directly from a Terminal, I don't get any prompt for the passphrase (this is the expected behavior):

```
$ git push remotename master
```

but if I run the same command from within Fabric, I do get a prompt for passphrase:

```
>> c.local("git push remotename master")
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/name/private/mykey'
```

That happens even though I added the key to the ssh agent (`ssh-add -K ./mykey`)

How can I make sure the Fabric version does not prompt me for a passphrase?

Comment: Do you run `fabric` under the same user? Do you run it from a terminal that has access (shell has necessary environment variables) to `ssh-agent`?

Comment: yes the `fab` command is run from the same terminal with the same user

Comment: Tried setting env variable `export SSH_PASSPHRASE="passphrase"` or enabling ssh-agent forwarding in fabric? [link](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/env.html?highlight=forwarding#forward-agent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first what URL is used locally:

```
c.local("git remote -v")
```

It should not ask for a key located in '`./`', unless there is a `~/.ssh/config` file which has specified the private key using a relative path (not a good practice).

Comment: Sorry I did not want to leave out the right path in my question so I changed the path and put a relative one instead (quicker). Sorry for the confusion, I am editing my question.

Comment: @David OK. Do you have a `~/.ssh/config` file? And what does the URL looks like?